# Не сохраняется словарь в сессии django

Tags: python, django, сессия

Есть код:

```
class AddToCartView(MainTemplate):

def post(self, request, **kwargs):
    post = request.POST
    item_id = int(post.get('id'))
    count = int(post.get('count'))

    if 'cart' not in request.session:
        request.session['cart'] = {}
    print("before:", request.session['cart'])
    if item_id not in request.session['cart']:
        request.session['cart'][item_id] = count
    else:
        old = int(request.session['cart'][item_id])
        request.session['cart'][item_id] = old + count
    print("after:", request.session['cart'])
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'result': 'success'}))


class GetCartItemsView(MainTemplate):

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        if 'cart' in request.session:
            print('send:', request.session['cart'])
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'items': request.session['cart'], 'result': 'success'}))
        else:
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'items': None, 'result': 'success'}))
```

Когда пользователь в первый раз добавляет товар в корзину, лог такой:

```
('before:', {})
('after:', {3: 1}) # 3 - ид товара, 1 - количество
('send:', {3: 1})
```

Если после этого добавить другой товар, лог такой:

```
('before:', {3: 1})
('after:', {3: 1, 12: 1})
('send:', {3: 1}) # где 12 товар?
```

Можно попробовать добавить другой товар:

```
('before:', {4: 1}) # почему 4?
('after:', {26: 1, 4: 1}) # что с сортировкой?
('send:', {4: 1}) # 26 пропал
```

Уже голову сломал с этими словарями в python. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: [Когда сохраняются сессии](https://djbook.ru/rel1.8/topics/http/sessions.html#when-sessions-are-saved)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, для добавления новых значений и изменения старых в сессиях нужно использовать сохранение

```
request.session.save()
```

Или

```
request.session.modified = True
```